# Adding CSS to API using FLASK

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have been trying to add CSS to my webpage using flask but it's not happening. If I run my webpage independently, it shows the CSS effects. But when I run the python code it displays plain HTML form.

> This is HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-g">
    <title>Forms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/view" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="name">Name
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>E-mail
                <input name="email" type="email">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Password
                <input name="pass" type="password">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>
                <input name="file" type="file">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit">
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

> This is the python code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("forms.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.7', port=int(8000), debug=True)
    print("Server Started successfully")
```

Comment: Well, `"{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"` and `"C:\Python\test1\static\css\style.css"` are clearly different paths. Why don't you just have one `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">`?

Comment: I did that to check if the HTML file is taking CSS independently.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight issue with your code.

Try adding the following as href for stylesheet:

```
url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')
```

Argument filename must have the path of file inside static folder.

Comment: I hope you can now accept my answer, since it worked well.